# Create a .wav file of a certain frequency with PHP

Tags: php, audio

I'm a rookie with this stuff so go easy...

All I want to do is construct a simple tone of a certain frequency using PHP. It should output a .wav file which can be inserted straight into a HTML audio tag.

I really have no idea where to begin as I don't even understand how audio data is stored. Can anyone suggest a resource or help me out directly?

It would be muchly appreciated :)

P.S there is one similar question, though I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you use external programs besides PHP? If so, I recommend using [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html) to generate the audio file on the server and then pass it through. To generate a 3 sec sine at 1 kHz, you'd use: `sox −n output.wav synth 3 sine 1000`

Comment: Presumably with  by creating the correct data structure this would be possible in php as well. It may be a matter of finding documentation of the .wav file format in order to do this.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you wish to use PHP? I don't believe there is anything in PHP to help you do this other than as @TomB suggested, looking up the specifications and writing binary data to file.

Comment: I did briefly look into it out of sheer curiosity. I'd love to be able to program a song in PHP using loops and objects. I found a couple of things that may help: http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/reading-16-bit-wav-file-318740.html? , http://andrewfreiday.com/2010/04/29/generating-mp3-waveforms-with-php/ http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1932-PHP-Generates-audio-data-files-in-the-WAV-format.html. Hopefully that may help steer you in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

Try this. (It uses SoX so it's not a pure PHP solution but it works well.

Your HTML

```
<embed height="50" width="100" src="/test.php?tone=1000">
```

Your PHP

```
<?php
    $tempFile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'AUD') . '.wav';
    $pitch    = (int)$_GET['tone'];

    exec("sox -n $tempFile synth 5 sin $pitch");

    header('Cache-Control: max-age=604800');
    header('Content-type: audio/x-wav');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($tempFile));
    readfile($tempFile);
```